# Parenthesized context managers work in python 3.9 but not 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement, python-3.9, contextmanager

So I have this simple example of a `with` statement.
It works in Python 3.8 and 3.9:

```py
class Foo:
    def __enter__(self, *args):
        print("enter")

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("exit")

with Foo() as f, Foo() as b:
    print("Foo")
```

Output (as expected):

```
enter
enter
Foo
exit
exit
```

But if I add parentheses like this it only works in Python 3.9:

```py
class Foo:
    def __enter__(self, *args):
        print("enter")

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        print("exit")

with (Foo() as f, Foo() as b):
    print("Foo")
```

Output in 3.8:

```
  File "foo.py", line 8
    with (Foo() as f, Foo() as b):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know, I could just remove the parentheses but I don't understand why it works in Python 3.9 in the first place.
I could not find the relevant change log.

Comment: That's weird. Parenthesized context managers are only available from [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers) as far as I know. It works for me also in Python 3.9 but strangely Pycharm highlights it as a syntax error (even though it doesn't actually raise one)

Comment: This bug might be related https://bugs.python.org/issue12782

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Parenthesized context managers are mentioned as a new feature](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers) in [What’s New In Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html). The changelog states:

> This new syntax uses the non LL(1) capacities of the new parser. Check
> [PEP 617](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/) for more details.

But [PEP 617](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0617/) was already accepted in Python 3.9, as described in [its changelog](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#new-parser):

> Python 3.9 uses a new parser, based on [PEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) instead of [LL(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser). The new
> parser’s performance is roughly comparable to that of the old parser,
> but the PEG formalism is more flexible than LL(1) when it comes to
> designing new language features. We’ll start using this flexibility in
> Python 3.10 and later.

It was even already part of [the Python 3.9 grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/grammar.html):

> ```
> with_stmt:
>     | 'with' '(' ','.with_item+ ','? ')' ':' block 
>     | 'with' ','.with_item+ ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block 
>     | ASYNC 'with' '(' ','.with_item+ ','? ')' ':' block 
>     | ASYNC 'with' ','.with_item+ ':' [TYPE_COMMENT] block 
> with_item:
>     | expression 'as' star_target &(',' | ')' | ':') 
>     | expression
> ```

My guess is that because the LL1 parser was officially removed in Python 3.10, only then it was considered a new feature, while still being supported in 3.9.